# Check toll roads in a route with Here Maps

Tags: here-api

I am calculating a route between two points. I get response OK and when I check it I can see this (click on image to maximize):

[image]

The element with index 15 intro maneuver array show an instruction for the A-2 spanish road and a note indicanting that A-2 is a tollroad with length 272km and this is totally wrong. A-2 is a spanish motorway without tolls, it never has had tolls.

I don't know if this is a particular api error or I am missing something.

Any help?

Regards

Edit: I added query example. See in the json output leg with index [8] A-2 road is tagged as tollRoad and it isn't.

https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id=XXXXXXXX&app_code=XXXXXXXXXX&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Adisabled%3Btollroad%3A0&representation=display&routeattributes=waypoints%2Csummary%2Cshape%2Clegs%2Cgroups&maneuverattributes=direction%2Caction&language=es-es&alternatives=0&legAttributes=length%2CtravelTime&waypoint0=40.6325%2C-3.16017&waypoint1=41.390205%2C2.154007&jsoncallback=H.service.jsonp.handleResponse

Comment: Please provide your query to help us provide an appropriate answer.

Comment: Post edited and query provided. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Code tollRoad in maneuver response doesn't necessarily mean it has a tollbooth and you shouldn't use that information for getting road information. In this case, the entire A2 stretch is made of several links. You can view all the link information by using the below query. We recommend using link attributes for usable link specific information. Replace app id and code placeholders with actuals.

```
https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=geo!40.6238258,-3.152014&waypoint1=geo!41.390205,2.154007&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&app_id={YOUR-APP-ID}&app_code={YOUR-APP-CODE}&representation=linkPaging&language=de-de&returnElevation=true&maneuverAttributes=position%2Clength%2CtravelTime%2CstartAngle&instructionFormat=text&routeAttributes=waypoints%2Csummary
```

Below is the part of the response you get from the above query. Here you can notice that, A2 road itself is made of several links where some have exits. But when it comes to the last link the user has no way to return than to take AP-2 road which has a tollbooth. Hence the last link of A2 is marked as tollRoad. 
[image]

In your maneuver query, all these links are combined and represented as one (for ease) and hence coded as tollRoad due to same explanation: If user takes this maneuver stretch of 272 km fully he has to go through AP-2 toll booth road. Hope you find this explanation complete and useful. Happy Coding!

Comment: I understand what you say but I need some way to calculate total lenght of a trip across toll roads. With the actual logic you explained me I can't use the flag tollRoad reliably. Another solution for that?

Comment: You can use the link flag attributes in the above query shown.

Comment: If you say "Code tollRoad in the response doesn't necessarily mean it has a tollbooth" then I can't use that link flag for calculate total length across tollroads.

Comment: You can use it if you are using the link query response data length attribute and not maneuver query response(you raised this question on).

Comment: If your example, in the last link -80631495, the flag tollRoad would be useful for me if the roadNumber (A-2 in that case) was a real toll road. I don't know if I am not explaining well my question or If I am not understanding you completely.

Comment: It is toll because if you reach that point you have no other way than to go to AP-2 road. We also provide tollRoadDistance for a calculated route by setting routeattribute=summaryByCountry parameter. Example:https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=geo!40.6238258,-3.152014&waypoint1=link!-594710932&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxx&representation=linkPaging&language=de-de&returnElevation=true&maneuverAttributes=position%2Clength%2CtravelTime%2CstartAngle&instructionFormat=text&routeAttributes=waypoints%2CsummaryByCountry

Comment: Hi again, I have been testing you sample and it's ok, with links information I could get the total distance across tollroads but I couldn't get a reliable list with the names of the toll roads. With the logic implemented in the response I would be getting as toll road the road A-2 in the two last links and that is simply false, because with the response data I can't figure out if it's a real toll road or not. I think that link response would need a new attribute 'realTollRoad: true' in all links that are part of AP-2 or at least in the first.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. We shall inform our internal team of your suggestion and leave it to their discretion.